# c++ default parameters class members

Tags: c++, class, parameters, default, members

```
class bst
{
private:

typedef struct nod
{
  int data;
  nod* left;
  nod* right;
  nod(int key):data(key),left(NULL),right(NULL){}
}node;
 node* root;

public:

void create();
void add(int key,node*curr=root);
void c2ll();
void print(){}
```

The code doesn't compile...
I get the below errors.

```
ain.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:7:12: error: call to ‘void bst::add(int, bst::node*)’ uses the default argument for parameter 2, which is not yet defined
   bt.add(50);
            ^
In file included from bst.cpp:1:0:
bst.h:14:8: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘bst::root’
  node* root;
        ^
bst.h:19:28: error: from this location
 void add(int key,node*curr=root);
                            ^
bst.h:14:8: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘bst::root’
  node* root;
        ^
bst.cpp:10:34: error: from this location
 void bst::add(int key,node* curr=root)
```

Any suggestions would be welcome...I am trying to avoid writing a wrapper method and instead use the default functionality provided by c++

Comment: As the error says you cant set default parameters to non-static member variables. You should overload add to take only the key and call the one taking two parameters with root as the second parameter.

Comment: @Borgleader: You should make that an answer.

Comment: so, that would be equivalent to writing a wrapper function.Is there anyway I can get away without writing that wrapper function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard (8.3.6 Default arguments)

> 9. ...Similarly, **a non-static member shall not be used in a default argument**, even if it is not evaluated, unless it appears as the
>      id-expression of a class member access expression (5.2.5) or unless it
>      is used to form a pointer to member (5.3.1). [ Example: the
>      declaration of X::mem1() in the following example is ill-formed
>      because no object is supplied for the non-static member X::a used as
>      an initializer.

```
int b;
class X {
int a;
int mem1(int i = a); // error: non-static member a
// used as default argument
int mem2(int i = b); // OK; use X::b
static int b;
};
```

You could overload function `add`. For example

```
void add( int key );

void add( int key, node *curr );
```

The first function would use `root` by default. It could simply call the second function passing as the second argument the node root.

Comment: the problem i have is it's a recursive function...void add( int key );....i need the node* in evry stack frame, hence i made it a parameter

Comment: @basav As I have written in my updated post the first function could call the second recursive function.:) So there is no problem.

Comment: @basav  Usually such approach is used for recursive function void reverse( char *s ). The function itself is not recursive but it calls overloaded function void reverse( char *s, size_t n ) like reverse( s, strlen( s ) );

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the definition for the method:

```
void add(int key,node*curr=root);
```

`root` isn't defined in the context you're using it. If you mean the member variable `node* root`, there is no way to default to member variables in the member functions, but you could set NULL(0) as the default and check it in the definition.

```
void bst::add ( int key,node*curr=NULL)
{
     if(curr==NULL) {
         curr= this->root;
     }
}
```

Comment: agreed on the parameters and member variables co-relation...nice example

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways.

Either use a "magic" default:

```
void add(int key, node* curr = NULL)
{
    if (curr == NULL)
        curr = root;
    // ...
}
```

or ditch the default altogether and use an overload:

```
void add(int key, node* curr)
{
    // ...
}

void add(int key)
{
    add(key, root);
}
```

My personal preference is the latter, but you shouldn't really expose the node type in the tree's interface at all, as that would let users of the tree ruin its balancing.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

`const node* root = NULL;
void add(int key,node*curr=root);`

You can check the actual running example here:
http://ideone.com/tJ1r29

Comment: hmm, if the root node is const it won't be possible to, eventually, add another node to the left or right of the root node...